# Only Courier-Fonts with Phantomjs 1.7/1.8/1.9, perhaps CSS specific

Tags: phantomjs

Since updating to OpenSuse 12.2 I cannot use phantomjs (updated from 1.5 to Version 1.8.1 64bit) any longer to create screenshots. The problem is a missing font support for serif/sansserif fonts. Only a courier/monospace like font is used.

Additionally phantomjs is really slow on rendering (5 seconds and more **--> solved**).

I tried to install packages like google-droid-fonts, free-ttf-fonts, bitstream-vera-fonts, freetype, font-config - but the only result are some other ugly fonts used.

Does anybody knows how to configure OpenSuse 12.2 to enable some useable fonts (like googles droid fonts) as fallback in phantomjs? Or did I miss to install a important font-render-lib (slow rendering)?

**Update**

- Building from source solved the performance issue
- Installing the Microsoft Core fonts like "Arial" etc did not help
- "fc-match" returns the right results
- an "strace -e open" shows, that phantomjs access the configs under /etc/fonts alright

**Update 2**

- The problem seems to originate in the CSS of my project. Trying different sites, most are well rendered.
- Tested version PhantomJS 1.9 with the same results
- Public URL to reproduce the bug: http://www.berlin.de/kennedy/

Comment: Building phantomjs from source solved the performance issue, but fonts are still ugly. This seems to be an opensuse problem...

Comment: The Mircosoft core fonts are installed now, SuSeconfig triggered multiple times and the command 'fc-match georgia' even returns the right results. But phantomjs, even in version 1.7 still uses courier as font for everything.

Comment: I've also been unable to get PJS to use the fonts installed on my debian system and seeing the same results as your opensuse system so I do not think it is a system-specific issue. I have tried installing font packages and doing some config jiggery to no avail.

Comment: I've searched for a bug report concerning this issue on PJS-Github, but could not find any. If someone wants to prepare some examples for reproducing it...

Comment: In some way, it seems to be a problem with the CSS. By preparing simple examples to reproduce the problem, I get correct results. So there seems to be no OS relevant or font-config issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by some major CSS rewrites including an update of Twitter Bootstrap. In some way some CSS rules interfered with the correct rendering.

With newer OS versions, I cannot reproduce the bug, either.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, installing the urw-fonts package solved it for me.

In my case no fonts where rendering at all, so this might not be the solution in your case, but worth a try:

> yum install urw-fonts

Comment: I've searched for package with a similar name but could not find one. Other font-packages did not helped. Probably the distributions are different in this case, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps this is specific to CentOS, which is what I'm using

Comment: That fixed my issue I had on CentOS. Thank you a lot Michael! :)