# Phantomjs not render hebrew fonts

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJs 1.9.2 on Centos 6.3 to for automated ui tests. When a test fails,
 screenshots are saved to the server.

My problem is that even though the screenshots are saved, they do not contain readable fonts.

So if the website reads like this:

> חיים טכנולוגיים

the screenshot of the site will look like this:

> םםםםםםםםםםםםם

So, instead of the actual letters, it renders and saves little boxes.

The system is centos 6.3. Freetype and Fontconfig are also installed.

How could I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you save the screenshots in pdf or png? Have you tried updating (compiling) phantom to 1.9.7?

Comment: I am saving screenshot in jpeg, and taking perfect screenshot on my local machine in any language. but on server it render only english language fonts.

Comment: we update the phantomjs. now its version is 1.9.7 .  But still fonts are coming like boxes

Comment: possible duplicate of [phantomjs screenshot font missing, boxes rendered instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029002/phantomjs-screenshot-font-missing-boxes-rendered-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use python code for taking screenshots of website. there are two module which will do whatever you want **pyvirtualdisplay** & **selenium**. Install them and write a class to create screenshot and call it with command line with your code.
Best of luck...

Answer (score 3):

follow these steps:

in /usr/share/fonts/ I added a folder named arial with the arial.ttf for hebrew
I ran fc-cache -vf.
That's it! I did not edit or change fonts.conf or did anything else as suggested in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to fix the same problem myself. I ended up doing what's suggested in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029002/phantomjs-screenshot-font-missing-boxes-rendered-instead?rq=1). Well, sort of. I skipped some of the steps:

1. in `/usr/share/fonts/` I added a folder named `arial` with the `arial.ttf` for hebrew
2. I ran `fc-cache -vf`.
3. That's it! I did not edit or change `fonts.conf` or did anything else as suggested in the link.

Granted, I still had a little trouble with parts of the page (I'm guessing it was because they were using fonts other than arial), but I ended up not needing them. Hopefully that'll be good enough for you too!

Comment: how you insatll arial.ttf fonts on server? Can you share your commands with me.

Comment: @user3660402 I just found it somewhere, I didn't install it. Either `locate` it or... y'know, just [download it](http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/A/Arial.html)

Comment: Awesome, a year later and it helped me alot. thanks.