# Text squares appearing in phantomjs on linux rather than words

Tags: python, linux, phantomjs

Using centos6. Project is in python running selenium and phantomjs-1.9.8.

I checked on my local computer (Windows 8.1) and the project still works fine and when I save a screenshot the text show it has rendered correctly.

Also on my linux server it worked great for one evening after I installed the relevant packages and ran it.

In that time I only shut down the server and started again, and now when I saved the screenshot to see what was wrong it is displaying only squares for text.

I searched around and it seems to be a common issue but had no idea about going about fixing it. All the suggestions seemed very convoluted. I see some possible fixes on github but I have no idea how to use those 'forks' they are just code with annotated text with no explanation on how to use them. So what are you supposed to do with them?

I dont get why it worked initially then stopped working after reboot. Not saying that is the reason but that's all I can think that changed.

Any ideas?

Here is related discussion: https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=460

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

```
yum install urw-fonts
```

garnered from:

[phantomjs screenshot font missing, boxes rendered instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029002/phantomjs-screenshot-font-missing-boxes-rendered-instead)